# TabBar inside detail view of SplitViewController.

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad, popover

I am trying to embed a Tabbar in the Detail side of a Split View Controller. The way I have done is that in the Storyboard I have the TabBarController as the DetailViewController and from there I have a couple of Navigation Controllers hooked to views ( separate tabs which are of type DetailViewController).

The problem I am facing is that out of two tabs which I have added, only one tab shows the button  for showing the Master view in the Portrait mode.

I am new to iOS development, and would deeply appreciate any help towards solving this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for the UITabBarController: "*When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.*"

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I have seen an example of MultipleMasterViewControllers from Apple , where they have a TabBar embedded inside the MasterView. I was hoping to accomplish the same on the Detail side. Here is the link : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: The example you linked to uses a table view to make the selections.  It could be changed to use a UITabBar and I think that would be OK.  The problem (as documented) only arises when you try to use a UITabBarController.

Comment: Thanks for providing the direction Philip. I was able to use a TabBar inside the Detail View and it has worked out for me.